# VS Code Anaconda: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I'm getting this error, although I have Anaconda installed. The VS Code Environment has Anaconda selected but the integrated terminal in VS Code cannot detect the Anaconda modules. 
I also tried adding Anaconda python to the Environment Variables(Path) but it selects the python installation(installed from python website) by default.
[image]

Comment: Did you append the anaconda python installation to the beginning or the end of the PATH variable?

Comment: Windows 10: I moved it right at the top!

Comment: Could you a) execute  "echo %PATH%" both in the VS Code integrated terminal and a cmd started outside of VS b) check the result of "where python" both in the VS Code command line and in a cmd started outside? Report any diffeernces in the outcomes

Comment: I got it fixed. All i did was remove default python path from Environment variables, add anaconda python path, and "Restarted". Earlier i did all the things but did not restart my computer.

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen from the prompt in the VS Code terminal **the Anaconda environment hasn't been activated yet** (missing `(base) C:\Users\...`). This is a known issue with VSCode, and the easiest workaround is to activate conda manually via `conda activate`. If this doesn't work the conda intitialization has probably been deselected during the installation process and you need to issue the `conda init` command directly from the `../Anaconda3/condabin/` subfolder.